# Access protected member function in C++

Tags: c++

There are two external class (A and B)that I cannot change. I would like to access protected member of the class A:: doSomething in C (which I can do edit). Is there any way to access it. I understand its not good practice but I did not find any other way of doing it.

```
// External code starts
struct A {
    friend class B;
protected:
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
protected:
    void doSomething() {
        A a;
        a.doSomething();
    }
};

// External code ends

// This will not compile as doSomething is a protected member.
struct C : B {
protected:
    void doSomethingElse() {
        A a;
        a.doSomething();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friendship is not transitive, so inheriting from `B` doesn't help with this.

Inherit from `A` and form a pointer-to-member to `doSomething`:

```
struct Helper : A
{
    static constexpr auto ptr = &Helper::doSomething;
};
```

Use that pointer to call a function on `a`:

```
void doSomethingElse()
{
    A a;
    (a.*Helper::ptr)();
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly I was looking for. Thanks @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Is this pointer working on original `A` objects, which are not also `Helper`? Or could/should the pointer by built with `&A::doSomething` instead?

Comment: Yes it points to A original object and only works with `&Helper::doSomething` not with`&A::doSomthing`.[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7G9nds5nh)